# How to add a total row at the end of the table in t-sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to add a row of sums as the last row of the table. For example:

```
   book_name   |   some_row1   |   some_row2   |   sum   
---------------+---------------+---------------+----------
    book1      |   some_data11 |   some_data12 |   100
    book2      |   some_data21 |   some_data22 |   300
    book3      |   some_data31 |   some_data32 |   500
 total_books=3 |   NULL        |   NULL        |   900
```

How can I do this? (T-SQL)

Comment: There is no last row in a table. Only an `ORDER BY`. This is an important thing to understand.

Comment: *How to add a total row at the end of the table in t-sql?* Simple answer: Don't. This is something you should do in your presentation layer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `union all` :

```
select book_name, some_row1, some_row2, sum 
from table t
union all
select cast(count(*) as varchar(255)), null, null, sum(sum)
from table t;
```

However, `count(*)` will give you `no of rows` available in table, if the `book_name` has `null` value also, then you need `count(book_name)` instead of `count(*)`.

Answer (score 2):

Try with ROLLUP

```
SELECT  CASE 
            WHEN (GROUPING([book_name]) = 1) THEN 'total_books'
            ELSE [book_name] END AS [book_name],some_row1, some_row2
        ,SUM(]sum]) as Total_Sales
From    Before
GROUP BY
        [book_name] WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: When I use GROUP BY, I can select columns that are in the GROUP BY or in an aggregate so it doesn't work I think, at least in ms sql server.

Answer (score 0):

I find that `grouping sets` is much more flexible than `rollup`.  I would write this as:

```
select coalesce(book_name,
                replace('total_books=@x', '@x', count(*))
               ) as book_name,
       col2, col3, sum(whatever)
from t
group by grouping sets ( (book_name), () );
```

Strictly speaking, the `GROUPING` function with a `CASE` is better than `COALESCE()`.  However, `NULL` values on the grouping keys is quite rare.